# How to add AnyObject type variable in Tuples

Tags: swift

How can we give AnyObject type  to one of the parameters in tuple in Swift?
Like:

```
var abc = (AnyObject Type, String)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use AnyObject type parameters in Tuple by import Foundation

```
var abc : (AnyObject, AnyObject)
abc = ([1,2,3,4],2)
```

We can also give AnyObject type parameters in Tuple by the use of "Any" Protocol

```
var http200Status : (Any,String)
http200Status = (200, "Success")
```